# update within by and drop

Tags: r, data.table

Hello guys and happy new year,
I was wondering if `data.table` could handle an update executed based on a select for each by-group.

```
R) a=data.table(x=c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),y=c(1,2,3,3,2,1))
R) a
   x y
1: a 1
2: a 2
3: b 3
4: b 3
5: c 2
6: c 1
```

If I want to update on a condition within each by-group I need to do the select in `j`, but this is more of an `i` thing (selection).

```
R) a[,c:=ifelse(y==max(y),"yes","no"),by=x]
R) a
   x y   c
1: a 1  no
2: a 2 yes
3: b 3 yes
4: b 3 yes
5: c 2 yes
6: c 1  no
```

Can I do the same using an option something like  `a[y==max(y),c:="yes",by=x,within.by=TRUE]` I think it would be much faster

Second question, is it scheduled to get a drop argument in `data.table`, to be able to do
`DT[drop="x,y,z"]` that would essentially be `DT[,':='(x=NULL,y=NULL,z=NULL)]`

Comment: Don't use `ifelse`. `a[,c:= y==max(y),by=x]` is faster.

Comment: fair enough but then I need 2 lines

Comment: You do not need two lines: `a[,c:= c("no", "yes")[(y == max(y)) + 1],by=x]`.

Comment: fair enough but then I need 2 lines ` a[,c:= y==max(y),by=x]` then ` a[as.logical(c),d:="yes"][as.logical(!c),d:="no"]`

Comment: On the second part `:=` takes multiple LHS: `DT[,c("x","y","z"):=NULL]`

Comment: But all this is not really answering the first question, selecting in `j` would be much longer isn't it ?

Comment: I don't understand why it matters if a column contains "yes"/"no" or "TRUE"/"FALSE" in a data.table. The information is the same and you won't print an object with a size common for data.tables on paper. A logical needs less memory and thus should be preferable.

Comment: @Roland. +1 Technically, a logical column uses 4 bytes on 32bit and 4 bytes on 64bit, too. A character column uses 4 bytes on 32bit (pointer to CHARSXP; R's global cache of unique strings) and 8 bytes on 64bit (pointers are 8 bytes on 64bit). So logical is the same size as character on 32bit (no saving), but half on 64bit (which is quite a bit).  Probably `bit` package would be the real saving, which is 32 times less, or 64 times less (I think). Haven't used `bit` with `data.table`, yet, though.

Comment: The problem is not about TRUE/FALSE yes/no which was an example. The question is that, as far as I know if I want to do an update in a by-clause, any select has to be handle in the `j` and not the `i`. As a consequance I am guessing it will be slow. Would that be the case ?

Comment: @statquant I'm not following this last comment I'm afraid. But I'll make a guess as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, following and building on comments: `which.max(x)` may be faster than `x==max(x)`.

From `?which.max` :

> **Value of `which.min` and `which.max`**
>
>   An integer of length 1 or 0 (iff x has no non-NAs), giving the index of the first minimum or maximum respectively of x. If this extremum is unique (or empty), the results are the same as (but more efficient than) `which(x == min(x))` or `which(x == max(x))` respectively.

So, maybe something like :

```
DT[,c:="no"]
w = DT[,list(IDX=.I[which.max(y)]),by=x]$IDX
DT[w,c:="yes"]
```

That uses `i` which might be what you're getting at. The result `w` is just one item per group, rather than `.N` per group, so it might be faster for that reason, too. Not just `which.max` alone per se. But of course if the max value can be tied then `which.max` will only return the first, so may not be appropriate depending on your data.

If you benchmark, ensure to make the data large (1GB+) and compare keyed by to unkeyed by as well.

Comment: Thanks @user1935457 for your correction adding `.I`. Not sure why others rejected it, but I've included it now.